# Input multiple KML files into Leaflet API

Tags: leaflet, javascript, kml

As we know, since the [WIndy Leaflet-kml](https://github.com/windycom/leaflet-kml) plugin has been developed we are able to input our KML files into the Leaflet map.

However I have one query regarding this:

How we can input a huge (at least several).kml files into this map?

Comparing it i.e with Google MyMaps, where we can place 8 single .kml layers (like 8 single .kml files). Could we do it the same in Leaflet using this plugin?

I tried this code, which works:

```
// Load kml file
fetch('lotA.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )

      })

fetch('lotB.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )

      })
```

... 2 files more, and last one:

```
fetch('LotD.kml')
      .then( res => res.text() )
      .then( kmltext => {

            // Create new kml overlay
            parser = new DOMParser();
            kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

            console.log(kml)

            const track = new L.KML(kml)
            map.addLayer(track)

            // Adjust map to show the kml
            const bounds = track.getBounds()
            map.fitBounds( bounds )

      })
```

Despite the code, which is valid, it can look awkward, when inpuit more files.~

I believe, it must be some solution with the `fetch()` reference. I was searching some info, but everywhere the `fetch()` option is related to some url address, on top of that, a single one:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

https://github.github.io/fetch/

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data

I was trying to do sth like this:

fetch(['lotA.kml'].['lotB.kml']), but this way is not good.

Do you know how to refactorize this code to make it more confined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on the answer placed here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/229225/loading-kml-files-into-leaflet-javascript-map/229289#229289

I would like to show the shorter code, that can be applied for this solution:

```
const addTrackAndBoundsFromKml = kmltext => {

// Create new kml overlay
 const parser = new DOMParser();
 kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext,"text/xml");

 const track = new L.KML(kml);
 map.addLayer(track);

 // Adjust map to show the kml
 map.fitBounds( track.getBounds() );

};

// load KML file
fetch('lotA.kml')
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( addTrackAndBoundsFromKml);

fetch('lotB.kml')
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( addTrackAndBoundsFromKml);

fetch('lotC.kml')
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( addTrackAndBoundsFromKml);

fetch('lotD.kml')
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( addTrackAndBoundsFromKml);

 fetch('Schematic.kml')
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( addTrackAndBoundsFromKml);


const files = ['lotA.kml', 'lotB.kml', 'lotC.kml', 'lotD.kml', 'Schematic.kml'];
for ( const file of files ) {
fetch(file)
  .then( res => res.text() )
  .then( addTrackAndBoundsFromKml);
}
```